# PHP Regex markdown from string

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I have this string: "`Download it from [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-admin/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-admin/)`";

And i'm trying to convert this markdown to actual HTML, i tried getting the matches like so:

```
preg_match_all('/[(.*?)]((.*?))/', $data[$toProcess], $links);
debug($links);
```

Yet this..did not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to convert this markdown into HTML.

ps. i'd rather not import the whole markdown library.

Comment: Why would you write that yourself? Use an existing library for that, e.g. [this one](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `[`, `]`, `(` and `)` as they are all regex meta-characters:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/', $data[$toProcess], $links);
```